# Flying from Canada to Australia w/ Stop in US (Baggage claim question)

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage, canada, international-travel

I leave Toronto INT Terminal to LAX - switching terminals to Tom Bradley INT terminal then on to Sydney Australia from there.

Questions: Do I need to claim my baggage in LAX because I'm switching terminals, re-enter security and still have time to make it to my next terminal? (2hours)

Comment: Normally yes, as the USA doesn't offer international transit, but since you're starting in Canada you might find that you'd have pre-clearance which changes things. Hopefully someone else can confirm

Answer (score 3):

You'll almost certainly clear US customs in Canada before getting on your flight, as Toronto Pearson has a US pre-clearance facility. So assuming your flight is a single booking you won't need to recheck.

Quoting the Toronto Pearson [website](http://www.torontopearson.com/Departing_to_usa.aspx#) on the matter (emphasis mine):

> For the majority of U.S. flights, guests leaving Toronto will go
>   through U.S. Customs in Toronto, **which allows you to arrive in the
>   United States as a domestic passenger**.

I once had a layover in Miami going to South America from Canada and didn't have to redo security and immigration in the US.